# Using 'apply' and 'recode' together

Tags: r

## I need to recreate some variables but instead of using a for loop I am trying to use 'apply' functions with the 'recode' function.

## Here is some of the code I've tried so far...

vars <- c("var", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5")

recode_vars <- apply(recode(mydata[, vars], "lo:129=0; 130:hi=1"))

## However, this produces the error message: Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default.

## Does anyone know how I could resolve this? Or just how to use 'apply' and 'recode' together in general?

Comment: Could you please use the following and share the outputted code: dput(mydata)

Comment: I've seen a lot of comments and it seems I should just specify what kind of data I'm working with... So, the variables consist of numeric values...   var1: 115 123 124 105 116.    var2: 86 136 122 115 128.   var3: 129 107 101 121 112.   var4: 105 111 109 129 125.    var5: 127 120 112 137 111. I'm trying to recode the variables using 'apply' and 'recode' so that all these values are 1 if greater than 130, and 0 otherwise. I also need to attach a prefix to the beginning of the recoded variable names.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `recode` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5")
mydata %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(vars), ~ recode(., "lo:129" = 0, "130:hi" = 1)))
```

-output

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    0    1    1    1    1
2    0    0    1    0    0
3    1    0    1    1    0
4    0    1    0    0    1
```

---

Or if we need to use `apply`, specify the `MARGIN` to loop across the columns - 2

```
mydata[vars] <- apply(mydata[vars], MARGIN = 2, 
     function(x) recode(x, "lo:129" = 0, "130:hi" = 1))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("lo:129", "130:hi"), 4 * 5, 
   replace = TRUE), ncol = 5, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:5))))
```

Comment: Thanks. So that created new variables for me, but its not recoding them as 1s and 0s. Also, what function would I be specifying in 'x'?

Comment: @Bryce then what is it recoding as?   I tested the code and it is working fine though

Comment: @Bryce I updated with a small reproducible example.  Your post didn't have any data for testing

Comment: It's keeping their original values of 129, 118, 131, etc. Also, I've tried pasting a prefix to the variable names to differentiate them, using this code, but it's not changing their names...    colnames(mydata[vars]) <- paste0("hi3b_", vars)
                                            mydata <- cbind(mydata, mydata[vars])

Comment: @Bryce I don't know about that.  As I mentioned, I created an example that is reproducible.

Comment: @Bryce your code is not correct in changing the column names

Answer (score 0):

Recode maps specific values to other specific values, when you seem to want retain values between 129 and 130 and flag all the others as low(0) or high(1).  It is hard to tell from your example, because it is uncertain if the inputs are integer.  You can easily do this using if-then or case_when logic.  Here is a quick solution to get you going.

```
library(purrr)
df <- data.frame(var1=runif(10, min = 128, max = 131), 
                 var2=runif(10, min = 128, max = 131))

n  <- df %>% map_dfc(~ case_when(. <= 129 ~ 0, . >= 130 ~ 1, T ~ .))
```

if the inputs are all integer, you can simply remove the last clause in the case_when statement as it will never be true.